# command line interface (TTY) disapears after 2 seconds

Tags: command-line, tty

When ever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into the TTY it fades out. For about 2 seconds you see the text all normal then it starts fading out and black screen appears.

I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to start the graphical interface. what's happening to it ?

Comment: If anyone does have the answer to this please forward even with a clean install it still does fade out.